# Hierarchical List sorting in the best way to make navigation faster

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, logic

I am getting a big array from a web service call through which i need to populate a dropdown.

```
[{"Level1":"A1","Level2":"A11","Level3:"A111"},
{"Level1":"A1","Level2":"A12","Level3:""},
{"Level1":"A2","Level2":"A21","Level3:"A212"},
{"Level1":"A2","Level2":"A22","Level3:""},
{"Level1":"A3","Level2":"","Level3:""},
{"Level1":"A4","Level2":"A41","Level3:"A412","Level4:"A4123"}]
```

My array is in this format.
I need to create list which should have a back button except in case.
Also the number of level is dynamic that means it can have Level 5,6,7... also.

The list options should be-

> A1,A2,A3,A4

If user clicks A2,the options shown should be-

> A21,A22

Now if user click on A21,it should show -

> A212

but if they click `A22`

it should select that value as `A22` does not have any further value.
Also if user selected back when they have option `A212`,it should show `A21` and `A22`.

What will be the best way to play with this array to get the fast result because i will be getting thousands of elements in it.

Comment: Your web service is returning invalid JSON.

Comment: please add a wanted result - presumably the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure.

In JavaScript you can organize it like this:

```
var root = { "A1": { "A11": .., "A12": .. }, "A2": { "A21": .., "A22": .. }, .. };
```

So you take keys from `root` objects and show them. If user clicks on A1, you take a value `root["A1"]` an so on.

To build it use simple insertion method (hope I get it right, please check):

```
function insert(node, elem, level) {
   var key = "Level" + level;
   var value = elem[key];
   if (!value) {
      return;
   }
   var childNode = node[value];
   if (!childNode) {
     childNode = {};
     node[value] = childNode;
   }
   insert(childNode, elem, level + 1);
}
```

Start by declaring `root = {}` and `insert(root, elem, 1)` where `elem` is an element in your array.